# Не помещается текст на кнопке

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн

При выборе пунктов: "профиль - править - доступ - добавить дополнительные способы входа..." появляется страница с кнопкой недостаточного размера для отображения текста:

> [image: addreg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма несколько изменилась с тех пор. Добавил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/6521):

> Добавить способ входа

В итоге будет выглядеть как-то так:

> [image: возможная реализация]